# convert Apk to ios or both with the same codes (cross platforms)

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform

Im an android developer , now i want my apps to be in iphones too, so is there any way to convert apk to ios or to write apps in android and ios with the same code ?

Answer (score 1):

`to write apps in android and ios with the same code?`

There are a lot of cross-platform frameworks such as

1. React native(javascript language).
2. Xamarin Forms(C# language)
3. Flutter(dart language developed by Google)

to develops an application which could run in both android and iOS platform. All the above framework will have at least more than 70 percent common codebase and the rest of the pieces of code will be written in android and iOS for platform-specific functionality. React Native and Flutter are the trending frameworks

`is there any way to convert apk to ios?`

I believe it is not possible. Even if you manage to convert, apple has strict rules in installing third-party applications. Thereby you won't be able to install the app in iOS

Comment: Thank you , i think that i gonna use xamarin

Comment: If it helps could you accept the answer so that it might be served as a reference for others

Comment: I less than 15 reputations im new here  but all votes are rcorded

Comment: For accepting answer you won't need any reputation. In fact, accepting the answer for your question will fetch you some reputation

Comment: I googled native code for android and i found (react native)